# Shopify access token refresh using Shopify .NET

Tags: oauth-2.0, shopify

I'm building a Shopify app in .NET. I successfully use Shopify .NET library to get an access token. However, it seems to be a temporary token, as it expires after some time. The functionality that needs access to the store runs as a background cloud service, therefore I cannot simply re-authenticate in the browser.

How can I either:

1. Get a permanent access token, or
2. Get a refresh token that I can then exchange for a temporary token?

Also, is there an "official" HTTP response code to tell that a token has expired?

Thanks!

Comment: Access tokens issued through the API should be permanent. Can you provide the API key and shop domain you're using? That will help us debug the issue.

Comment: @DavidUnderwood : I have the same problem as described. I use `https://test.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token` to get the `access_token` used in all following calls. At some time the app stops been authenticated and it requires login. Do you think that it's an internal problem of the ASP.NET part or from the oAuth authentication of shopify?